# Unable to identify elements using Appium inspection for hybrid cordova ionic iOS app

Tags: ios, appium

I am not able to identify the elements via appium inspector. When I click on any of the object, whole frame is getting selected. However some of the elements are able to locate.

I have tried with various iOS platform versions, appium desktop in both real device and simulator.

```
  Appium desktop version : 1.17.1
  Xcode version : 11.5
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "platformVersion": "11.4",
  "deviceName": "iPhone Simulator,
  "udid": “xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx….”,
  "bundleID": "mycompany.test”,
  "autoGrantPermissions": true,
  "noReset": true,
  "autoAccept": true,
  "automationName": "XCUITest"
  "xcodeConfigFile": ".xcconfig",
  "app": "mycompany.app",
```

Answer (score 0):

make your app build in debug mode so you can inspect elements in a webview, cordova applications run in the webview context. Make sure you set driver context to webview (here are more [details](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/index.html)). To inspect elements build the app locally and inspect in chrome or use device farms like [Gigafox](https://mobilelabsinc.com/products/gigafox-red). [Here](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/ionic/2018/09/30/e2e-testing-ionic-protractor-appium-e2e-testing.html) is a great tutorial on how to run Appium with ionic application

Comment: Thanks Slav. Verified that our app build is in debug mode. Still the issue persists.

Comment: Rose, appium inspector can't see webviews (per my knowledge), instead open your cordova app in chrome and inspect elements there. Here is more details on that https://appiumpro.com/editions/57-how-to-determine-element-locators-for-mobile-web-and-hybrid-apps